# Ultrawebgrid Event before/after group?

Tags: events, infragistics, ultrawebgrid

I'm working with a web application that uses the UltraWebGrid v10.3. I needed to group the data in the grid which I managed to get working with a `GroupByBox`.

Once the grid is grouped by a certain column, I want to remove/hide that column from the grid, I plan to achieve this using an event.

My question is, what are the events fired before and after a column header is dropped in the GroupByBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default when you group a column in the UltraWebGrid that column will be hidden.  This can be changed with the DisplayLayout.[GroupByColumnsHiddenDefault](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/ASPNET/2011.1/CLR4.0/?page=Infragistics4.WebUI.UltraWebGrid.v11.1~Infragistics.WebUI.UltraWebGrid.UltraGridLayout~GroupByColumnsHiddenDefault.html) property.  You should make sure that this is set to Yes which is the default value.

Comment: Thank you very much. I discovered this property just after I posted this question. Do you have any idea of the events fired when a column header is dropped in the GroupByBox?

Comment: The GroupColumn event will fire: http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/ASPNET/2011.1/CLR4.0/?page=Infragistics4.WebUI.UltraWebGrid.v11.1~Infragistics.WebUI.UltraWebGrid.UltraWebGrid~GroupColumn_EV.html